# How to change item in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to have a function randomly select a row from a CSV file and have a value from the row swapped for a random integer. I'm currently testing this on one row, by trying to swap 'x' out for a number.

I have tried different ways including using the panda library, but still can't get it.

```py
import pandas as pd
from os.path import isfile
import csv

def Create():
    if not isfile('Questions.csv'):
        with open('Questions.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
            Writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
            Writer.writerow(['Ball dropped from', 'x', 'metres. Calculate time taken to reach floor'])
    else:
        with open('Questions.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
            Writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
            Writer.writerow(['Ball dropped from', 'x', 'metres. Calculate time taken to reach floor'])

Reader = pd.read_csv('Questions.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(Reader, columns = [1, 2, 3])
col = 2
df[col] = df[col].replace('x', '25')
Reader1 = pd.read_csv('Questions.csv')
print(Reader1)
```

This code should change 'x' to '25' in the CSV file, and then should output the updated row.

[image]

Above is the data in the csv file

Comment: Please post sample CSV data

Comment: Why not sample one item, use the index to locate, then overwrite with whatever your random integer is? `df.loc[df.sample(1).iloc[0].name, 'your_column'] = np.random.randint()`

Answer (score 1):

But hold on, isn't it that you load data from csv into pandas, then you change data in pandas, and then you read csv again. I mean in order to change csv I suppose you should write mentioned pandas into that csv. It's not going to be changed otherwise pandas is not a live-stream of csv.

To write pandas into csv:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Reader1 = pd.read_csv('Questions.csv')
```

to

```
df.to_csv('Questions.csv')
```

you need to write the csv to update the csv file, you are just re-reading the original

Comment: That removes all the data from the csv file and changes to numbered rows and columns.

Comment: pandas assigns numbers to your index and columns if not specified when reading the csv...to only print out the data within the df you can use - df.to_csv('Questions.csv',header=False,index=False)

Comment: you can't dynamically update a csv without re-writing it after each update